# prepareForSegue is not calling for container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uicontainerview

View controller is loading initially from appdelegate. Later it gets managed by hiding and unhiding with animation. In that view controller prepareForSegue is not calling for an embedding container view.

In `AppDelegate`

```
+ (AppDelegate *) appDelegate {
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.videoViewController = [[PlayerViewController alloc] init];

        return YES;
    }
```

To display the view controller:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication];
AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[appDelegate videoViewController]show];
```

I tried to trigger embed segue from viewcontroller after displaying, but it's not even triggering prepareforsegue.

Comment: `[[PlayerViewController alloc] init];` Doesn't seem to be loading the `PlayerViewController` with its "storyboard/xib", so no `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Adding: If you have IBoutlet, there should be nil (because of previous reason).